# How to create an unicode instance from an unicode literal

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, unicode-literals

Due to some bug in a C extension, I'm getting unicode data with str instances, or in order words, str with no encoding at all and an unicode literal.

So, for instance, this is a valid unicode literal

```
>>> u'\xa1Se educado!'
```

And the UTF-8 encoded str would be:

```
>>> '\xc2\xa1Se educado!'
```

However, I get an str with the unicode literal:

```
>>> '\xa1Se educado!'
```

And I need to create an unicode instance from that. Using `unicode()` doesn't work, since it expects an encoding. I figured that `''.join(unichr(ord(x)) for x in s)`  does what I need, but it's really ugly. There has to be a better solution. Any ideas?

Comment: what version of Python you are working with? What is the extension which makes the problems? Could you correct it there?

Comment: Python 2.7. The extension isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, there has to be a way to decode it with whatever "encoding" python uses for unicode, and that's `raw_unicode_escape`.

```
>>> unicode('\xa1Se educado!', 'raw_unicode_escape')
u'\xa1Se educado!'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I get an str with the unicode literal: `'\xa1Se educado!'`

Not really, `\xa1` is not a Unicode-specific escape. `\xa1` in a byte string means byte number 161 and `\xa1` in a Unicode string means character (code point) number 161—same as `\u00A1`.

What you have is a byte string containing an ISO-8859-1 encoding of `¡Se educado!` instead of the UTF-8 encoding. In the ISO-8859-1 encoding each byte number happens to match the Unicode character of the same code point number. To decode an ISO-8859-1 byte string to a Unicode string use:

```
>>> '\xa1Se educado!'.decode('iso-8859-1')
u'\xa1Se educado!'
```

although actually if you are using Windows then the encoding is likely to be code page 1252 (`'windows-1252'`) rather than ISO-8859-1. They're similar encodings but not quite the same. Code page 1252 is the default ‘ANSI’ code page that Windows uses for non-Unicode applications in the Western European and US locales. If you are getting this data from a Windows non-Unicode application running on the same machine, you should decode it using the encoding `'mbcs'` which corresponds to whatever the locale-specific default code page is.

These are legacy encodings that cannot hold all Unicode characters. You will probably find the C extension cannot cope with characters outside of the current code page set at all.

Comment: Nope. The example was poor in that it matches the ISO-8859-1, but as soon as I have characters exclusive to unicode, it breaks and I get escaped \u sequences. For instance, u'€95.00' is coming up as '\u20ac95.00'. I'm pretty sure someone is writing raw python unicode somehow. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: There's no `\u` escape in a byte string—do you mean to say you have `'\\u20ac95.00'`? And yet you have `'\xa1'` (ie a literal byte 161, not `'\\xa1'`) for characters U+0000 to U+00FF?